# Semantics Issue: No matching function for call to 'displayBoard'

Tags: c++, call

I'm just calling a function with a 2D array as an argument. I don't see why it's telling me there's no function to call, I can see the function.
Here's the prototype, at the beginning of my code: 
    `void displayBoard(int [][COLS], int);`
here's the function calling displayBoard and the displayBoard function:

```
void playerTurn()
{
    char board[ROWS][COLS] = {{'*', '*', '*'}, {'*', '*', '*'}, {'*', '*', '*'}};
    char row, col;

    displayBoard(board, ROWS);
    cout << "Player X's Turn.\nEnter a row and a column to place an X.\nRow: ";
    cin >> row;
    cout << "\nColumn: ";
    cin >> col;
    //clear screen
    //edit contents of 2D array
    displayBoard(board, ROWS);
    cout << "Player O's Turn.\nEnter a row and a column to place an X.\nRow: ";
    cin >> row;
    cout << "\nColumn: ";
    cin >> col;
    //Validate each user's move (make sure there isn't an x or o already there
    //Ask for a re-input is validation fails
}

void displayBoard(const char board[][COLS], int ROWS)
{
    cout << setw(14) << "Columns" << endl;
    cout << setw(14) << "1 2 3 " <<  endl;
    cout << "Row 1:  " << board[0][0] << " " << board[0][1] << " " << board[0][2] << endl;
    cout << "Row 2:  " << board[1][0] << " " << board[1][1] << " " << board[1][2] << endl;
    cout << "Row 3:  " << board[2][0] << " " << board[2][1] << " " << board[2][2] << endl;
    cout << endl;
}
```

It gives me the error at both calls in the playerTurn function.
I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Semantics Issue: No matching function for call to 'displayBoard'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared before you function definitions

```
void displayBoard(int [][COLS], int);
```

Then in `playerTurn()` you call

```
displayBoard(board, ROWS);
```

Here `board` is a `char board[ROWS][COLS]` so the compiler looks to see if it has seen a function declared or defined named `displayBoard` that takes those parameters.  Since the compiler has not seen it it will issue an error.

To fix this you either need to change the decleration to

```
void displayBoard(const char board[][COLS], int ROWS);
```

Or you can just change the order of the functions and have `playerTurn()` defined before `displayBoard()`

Comment: I have function prototypes before any of my functions are written
   void displayBoard(int[][COLS], int);
   void playerTurn();

Comment: @InkySkies123 But do you have `void displayBoard(const char board[][COLS], int ROWS);` or `void displayBoard(int [][COLS], int);`.  I think that might be the real issue but if not I will delete this.

Comment: I moved the displayBoard function before the playerTurn function, and the error was gone, you must have been right!. Can you try explaining again what I did wrong with my definitions, because I don't quite understand how that got screwed up and why.

Comment: @InkySkies123 I have changed the answer.  let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

`board` in `playerTurn` contains `char`, but the parameter in `displayBoard` expects it to contain `int`.

Comment: Ah, thanks for catching that, that was going to bite me later, but it didn't fix the error.

Comment: xcode, has made it fairly clear that it has an issue with the 'displayboard' part of the function call. It put the red squiggly line under just that part in both calls.